# What should be the correct architecture in an e-commerce module

Tags: architecture, e-commerce, payment, order

I'm new in development & just developing an `e-commerce` platform. I'm just confuse about the flow of payment. Suppose I have a checkout page where after logged in user has to press the payment button and it will take him to  `Instamojo payment processor's` page and the after successfully making the payment they will be redirected to `success page`. I just wanted to know that should I submit the order details to my database when user clicks on the `payment` button or after making the payment. what i prefer is the after payment the order details will be stored. My problem is when user clicks on the `payment` button the left my page so after successfully payment or rejection of payment how may i store the details to database

Comment: From a users perspective: When I am redirected back to the vendor's site after making a payment, I am typically still logged in. This means that at least some session context must be preserved during the side-trip to the payment processor. That session context might also contain information about the order.

Comment: Yeah absolutely correct , I can store those value to session as soon as the user click on payment button the problem is when what if user fails to pay then ?

Answer (score 2):

Save the order when it is 'Placed'. Handle the payment separately.

Lots of things can go wrong with payment. Cards can be declined, payments can go through and then be withdrawn, redirects back to your page can fail, payment providers can go down, users can turn up and pay in cash.

You will want to have a record of the order before a payment is attempted so you can deal with these various scenarios.

The exact details of how you take a payment will vary depending on how you are doing it or which third party you get to do it for you. but in general:

- Redirect user to https://paymentgateway.com/payment?encodedorderdetails=dfgkdjghkfdj
- Payment gateway takes card details and processes payment
- payment gateway redirects user to https://yousite/paymentcomplete?paymentinfo=fsljkfksjdhfsdkjfh

You link up the payment detail with the order, update the order status to whatever the result of the payment attempt was and take whatever other business actions you want.

Comment: So in which process I will know that the order is confirmed ? and How may I send an order confirmation email to users? Because if user clicks on the `payment`as u said the payment may not be happened so what process I should send order confirmation email?

Comment: https://docs.instamojo.com/docs/payments-api

Comment: Thank you so much for making me understand about the flow

Comment: hey, I just want to ask you one question that is the time I place an order it is saved in the database in  `id` like `25` or `28` but after payment processed if I want to update the status field as completed then which `id` should I take an order id. That time the order id will be lost.

Comment: I believe you send your Id to instamojo as part of their process so they can send it back to you. You really should ask them for help, you pay for the service so they will be happy to assist your setup and advise on best practice

Comment: When user press the order button then one id should be generated in database then after payment how can i get that generated id again to modify  or change the status pending to complete